# Combinatoric recurrence question

Tags: combinatorics

Three types of counter are coloured blue, red and white. The blue and red counters are $1$ unit thick and the white counters are $2$ units thick. Let $C_n$ be the number of ways in which counters can be arranged in a pile of height $n$ units with no two red counters adjacent. For $n\ge 1$, prove that $C_{2n+2}-C_{2n}$ is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

To build a valid pile you either :

1. Add a blue counter (+1)
2. Add a white counter (+2)
3. Add a blue and then a red (+2)
4. Add a white and then a red (+3)

$$C_{k+3}=C_{k+2}+2C_{k+1}+C_{k}$$

1. $C_0=1$
2. $C_1=2$
3. $C_2=4$

Note that $$C_{2k+2}-C_{2k}=C_{2k+1}+C_{2k}+C_{2k-1}=2C_{2k}+3C_{2k-1}+C_{2k-2}$$ $$=2\left(C_{2k}-C_{2k-2}\right)+3\left(C_{2k-1}+C_{2k-2}\right)$$

And $(C_2-C_0)=3$, so $(C_{2k+2}-C_{2k})$ is a multiple of $3$ for all $k$.